# How to declare an `extern` variable in VBA?

Tags: vba, extern

In C, variables marked `extern` need only be declared locally, but may be defined externally. Is this possible with VBA? Thus I'm after like something like this:

```
DataSource_14.accdb:
    ' References CommonFunctions.accdb
    Public SOURCE_ID As Long = 14

    Public Sub Baz()
        Foo
        Bar
    End Sub 

CommonFunctions.accdb:
    Extern SOURCE_ID As Long    ' <- what's the proper way to declare this?
    Public Sub Foo()
        Debug.Print "Doing Foo stuff with source " & SOURCE_ID
    End Sub
    Public Sub Bar()
        Debug.Print "Doing Bar stuff with source " & SOURCE_ID
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Tools/References in VBA you can add a reference to the other database. Then you can use:

```
Application.Run "projectname.procedurename"
```

(the return value is a `Variant`)

The 'projectname' defaults to the database name, but can be changed in the VB Editor (Tools, VBAProject Properties).

However, this will not retrieve a public variable. This variable would need to be returned by a Function procedure.

Alternatively, the other database could be a *Library Database* (or Add-in). See [here](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/addins.htm) and [here](http://www.vb123.com/toolshed/07_access/libraries.htm).

I believe it would be possible to return a variable by creating a Library Database, and using a Class in this database to expose a field (property) of the Class. But creating a Function procedure is much simpler.

If possible, though, it is much easier to create a Module containing useful functions and copying this between databases. I believe that creating and using Access Add-ins (databases) can be problematic.